# Solmization with syllables - du da di

Tags: theory

First of all, I am an absolute noob regarding music, so please bear with me.

I am trying to understand an exercise (from my son's school lesson, where teacher seems to be reluctant to explain this in detail ...) about solmization with syllables "du da di". I am giving the solution to the exercise question as an image here: [image]

The question reads in english like:
Write down the corresponding solmization syllables below the notes.

The question is provided just with the notes, but without the syllables, of course.

I do not understand the rules for when to put what syllable below the notes.

I already did some gooling and searching in here, but could not find a hint about this. Regarding solmization I only find explanation about "do re mi fa so", so it seems to me this "du da di" syllable are some custom stuff.

So my questions are:
What kind of rule is behind this solmization? When do I put which syllable in? Is there any general convention about what syllables will be used (du da di) or is this just a convention that each teacher can agree with their students?

Comment: Kodaly and later, Gordon, came up with rhythmic names for various rhythms (!). It seems very complex and really not that enlightening. Personally, I find it fairly pointless.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't know this was done in German-speaking countries. Is this common over there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The names of the notes depend not on their length, but on their position in the measure. The six eighth notes per measure are named:

```
du  da  di  du  da  di
♪   ♪   ♪   ♪   ♪   ♪
```

No matter how long a note is, it gets the name of the position where it starts; e.g. a note which starts on the third eighth note would be a "di":

```
du  da  di  du  da  di
        ♩            
        di
```

So the example in the question would become:

```
du  da  di  du  da  di    du  da  di  du  da  di    du  da  di  du  da  di 
♪   ♪   ♪   ♪   ♪   ♪     ♩       ♪   ♩        ♪     ♪   ♩       ♩       ♪
du  da  di  du  da  di    du      di  du      di    du  da      du      di
```

I guess it's an exercise in keeping track of where you are in the rhythm, though it would probably be clearer if you sang "o-one three fou-our six" instead of "duuu di duuu di".

Comment: Counting numbers has worked for me for 60 yrs...

Comment: @Tim The problem in German is of course that "eins", "zwei" and "drei" all have the same vowel. If a whole class is singing "doo dah dee" you can easily hear (and see) when someone makes a mistake.

Comment: I'm guessing it's only a problem counting in German. French, Spanish, English and most other languages don't have numbers that sound similar.

Comment: More the position in the beat rather than which beat in the measure,  I think.

Comment: FWIW  in the USandA  a common method is "One-eee-and-aa; Two-eee-and-aa" for 16th-notes;  "One-and-aa,..." for triplets,  "One-and" for duplets.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this helps you to understand it more clearly:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, this was very helpful. Since only one answer can be marked as solution, I gave it to Uncle Bobs answer, but surely upvoted yours.